# Rotating texture in node mapping make texture gone after rotate more than 90°

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, transparency

I am rather new on blender, in this case i was making an eyeball
i want to combine transparent and glossy shader and in the last step i need to rotate the texture to make the transparent side facing front/ the iris but whenever i try to rotate the texture using node mapping color ramp in y axis, 
my texture gone when i rotate it after a certain degree its like having a wrong rotation pivot or something and make me unable to rotate the transparent side reaching the front
here is the screenshot :

[image][image]

blend file : http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52047

Thankyou and sorry if my explanation isnt clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rather try with the *Texture Coordinate "Object"* output, it looks much more controllable than *Generated*. [Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/texture_coordinate.html) for the manual explanation. Also don't forget to apply the rotation and scale of your object if you want the object axis to be aligned on the global (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: thankyou bro its work ,especially after i apply rotation and scale like you said